# How to know that my webpage has loaded after JS page change?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I need something like onPageFinished but for JS page load.
I need to inject some javascript after every page load, but onPageFinished not calling for js page load. Any way to listen to page load for Javascript page changes ?